# How to retrieve related Objects in Firebase Database in Swift (or Web)?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data saved to a Firebase Database with complex relationships indexed as outlined [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/structuring-data.html) similar to the example below.

```
  {
    "groups": {
      "alpha": {
        "name": "Alpha Group",
        "members": {
          "mchen": true,
          "hmadi": true
        }
      },
      ...
    },
     "users": {
      "mchen": {
        "name": "Mary Chen",
        // index Mary's groups in her profile
        "groups": {
           // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
           "alpha": true
        },
      },
      ...
    },
     "animals": {
      "dog": {
        "users": {
           // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
           "mchen": true
        },
      },
      ...
    },
  }
```

For my project, what I need to do is I need to get a list of group members for all users who like dogs. This means means getting one reference, then another, then another. If I want to get the group members of people who like dogs, I'd Fetch

1. `animals>dog>mchen`
2. `user>mchen>groups>alpha`
3. `groups>alpha ... members`(final result)

Given that this is all done asynchronously, how would I conduct these data retrievals with conditions of completion, chaining one to the next? I've already tried nesting completion handlers, and this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you're retrieving as json, you can parse it.

Comment: I'm using the swift functions outlined by Firebase, which are asynchronous right now. So you're saying I should download the entire JSON table and parse it on my device?

Comment: No that's not a good way

Comment: Didn't think so. Any tips on parsing JSON on demand on swift then?

Comment: Check [Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html) section, it can be helpful.

Comment: You'd do that by nesting completion blocks. So in the completion block for loading the users-who-like-dogs, you then load the groups-of-users. And in the completion block of that you'd load the group members. If you got stuck while writing that code, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).